# Decimal Counter with PWM

Tags: pwm, counter

I'm searching for a decimal counter ic which I can controll with PWM or another signal.
The basic counting ic is a [4017](http://www.dieelektronikerseite.de/Datasheets/CMOS/4017%20(Philips).pdf) I think, but in the Datasheet you can see that every new clock high pulse the ic counts, with no delay between it.
[image]

but I'm looking for an IC that counts and sets the outputs like this. Clock high 1 high, clock low 1 low, clock high 2 high, clock low 2 low... and so on

[image]

I hope you understand what I mean, and help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your diagram 2 shows, you will not get PWM from a 4017. You will get a series of individual pulses.

You can achieve what you require by ANDing each output with the clock signal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRt2Ny.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: However, you'll also get a glitch at the end of each output, since the clock will go high just before the outputs change. Probably not an issue, but you never know.

Comment: Good point. That's a glitch in my answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need all 10 outputs? You could pulse double, then use every 2nd output. 4017 can be chained to greater length in this application

An alternative would be silego programmable devices, which have analog innards to implement pwm also ...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOc3aDm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>